# Is this map an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $f : M_{2 \times 2} \to \Bbb{R}$ be given by 
$$
    \{ \{ a, b \}, \{ c, d \} \} \mapsto ad-bc
$$
To prove something is an isomorphism it has to be 1-1, onto and preserve structure.

Can someone tell me If I am doing this correctly?

The above is not 1-1 because if $ f( \{ \{ a_1, b_1 \}, \{ c_1, d_1 \} \}) = f( \{ \{ a_2, b_2 \}, \{ c_2, d_2 \} \})$ then $a_1 d_1 - b_1 c_1 = a_2 d_2 -b_2 c_2$. This is not 1-1 because there are multiple solutions to the above problem. 
So it is not an isomorphism.

On an additional note, Even though this is not an isomorphism because it is not 1-1, how would you go about proving if it is onto or not, I never understood that part.

Thanks.

Comment: What you've done is OK, though it would be more convincing if you included an example of the "multiple solutions" you claim.

Comment: As for onto, can you find a matrix that gets mapped to the number $17$? If so, is there anything special about the number $17$, or can you make something work for any old number?

Comment: @GerryMyerson would you mind clarifying the onto bit

Comment: How much clearer can I make "can you find a matrix that gets mapped to the number 17?"? You have a formula that takes a $2\times2$ matrix and gives back a number; can you choose an input so that the output will be $17$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes you can, ie a=20, b =1, c =3, d =1... I don't see how that proves it is onto though

Comment: It's just the first step. Now, can you use the same method that got you $17$ to get you $18$? or $-11$? or $\pi\sqrt2$? If yes, then you're done. If no, back to the drawing board --- find a simpler way to get $17$, one that's easy to tinker with to get the other numbers.

Comment: $M_{2 \times 2}$ and $\mathbb R$ have different dimensions, therefore they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the tuple $\{ \{ a, 0 \}, \{ 0, 1 \} \}$ :-)

**EDIT:** All such matrices are there in $M_{2 \times 2}$ and under your map $f$, they go to the point $a \in \Bbb{R}$. Thus, the map $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: @user130834: Surjective means onto. The function $f$ is onto but not $1-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the context of the problem is, but here is some additional insight. What you have is the determinant. It is a homomorphism in the sense that it preserves multiplication, i.e.
$$
\det(A\cdot B) = \det(A) \det (B)
$$
So the map preserves multiplications. It is also *onto* since given any determinant, one can easily construct a matrix with the determinant. As you point out, it is not 1-1. Just consider upper triangular matrix. You can change the off-diagonal value without changing the determinant.

Somehow I have a feeling that there is a follow-up question to the problem that will ask you to show that it is a group homomorphism between invertible matrices and non-zero reals with group operation being matrix multiplication and ordinary multiplication.